# Correct way to organize my DynamoDB tables

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, database-table

This is the first time I use DynamoDB. I have a question about how to organize my tables.

I own a table containing users, I will have words associated with those users.

Should I create a property with an array in the user or a new table? I will also have a history of the words searched by each user and I also have the same doubt.

What determines which way to go?

Comment: It all depends on the query you are going to fire on the table